# how can i make an image change with hover?

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I tried making an image change to another while hovering, but instead, the second one appeared without the first disappearing
this is the code, is there anything I did wrong.
hope you find the question clear

```css
.card {
  width: 130px;
  height: 195px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
}

.card .img-top {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.card:hover .img-top {
  display: inline;
}

.card {
  width: 130px;
  height: 195px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
}

.card .img-top {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.card:hover .img-top {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="redlo.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="first">
  <img src="whitelo.jpg" class="img-top" width="100" height="100" alt="second">
</div>
```

Comment: 1. I recommend to use background image, if want to change it with css.
2. With image you can use javascript to achieve same using img tag.
3. add two different clasess i.e. img-top-1, img-top-2, .card .img-top-1 { display : none;}
.card img-top-2 { display:inline}

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure if I understand your question right. On `.card:hover` the second image is shown above the first one and covers the first one so it is not seen anymore.

So your code is running well and there is no additional need to make the first image 'disapearing'.

But if you (however) want/need to do so just may add to your css:

```
.card:hover img:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

*Nice additonal notice: your css is doubled. You only need to write the classes `.card` `.card .img-top` and  `.card:hover .img-top` once ;-)*

---

**UPDATE: YOUR WORKING CODE WITH IMAGES**

Here you can see how your code is working correct. Just removed doubled css.

```css
.card {
  width: 130px;
  height: 195px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
}

.card .img-top {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.card:hover .img-top {
  display: inline;
}

.card {
  width: 130px;
  height: 195px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0000ff/ffffff&text=Image+one" width="100" height="100" alt="first">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ff0000/ffffff&text=Image+two" class="img-top" width="100" height="100" alt="second">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much , I just tried it and it works wonderfuly

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the height of your image is being 0

You can try:

```css
.card:hover .img-top {
  display: block;
}
```

if don't work add this to `.img-top` selector

```css
.card .img-top {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: No. The size of both images in both cases is correct given in html with `100x100px`. The code is working correct. In the actual example are no images used so you only see the alt attributes ... but no second image that covers the first one ... so you can still see the alt attribute from the first image on `:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```css
.card {
  width: 130px;
  height: 195px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
}

.img-top {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.card:hover .img-top {
  display: block;
}
.card:hover .img-top1 { display: none }
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="redlo.jpg" width="100" class="img-top1" height="100" alt="first">
  <img src="whitelo.jpg" class="img-top" width="100" height="100" alt="second">
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer fully

Comment: You were not hiding your first image when you do hover on card element and I just added display none to it. Rest of changes are just clean up